# C# Differences between operator ==, StringBuilder.Equals, Object.Equals and Object.ReferenceEquals

Tags: c#, object, stringbuilder, equals-operator, referenceequals

I have a question about `Object.Equals` and `Equals(object)`. My sample code is below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sb1 = new StringBuilder("Food");
        var sb2 = new StringBuilder("Food");
        Console.WriteLine(sb1 == sb2);
        Console.WriteLine(sb1.Equals(sb2));
        Console.WriteLine(Object.Equals(sb1, sb2));
        Console.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(sb1, sb2));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
False
True
False
False
```

But as far as I'm concerned `Object.Equals(sb1, sb2)` internally calls  `sb1.Equals(sb2)` so why does it give two different results?

Comment: You should come up with a better question title. The current doesn't mean anything. Please don't repeat tags in titles.

Comment: @ReferenceEquals: You are compare four methods of comparison. I modified your title to reflect your question a little better.

Comment: Why are you checking for equality on 2 stringbuilders? It is like checking a stream or textwriter for equality.

Answer (score 18):

You are missing another test:

```
Console.WriteLine(sb1.Equals((object)sb2)); // False!
```

StringBuilder does not override [`Equals(object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx), it **overloads** it with another [`Equals(StringBuilder)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccth01t4.aspx).

[`Object.Equals(object, object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k.aspx) is calling `Equals(object)`, so the result is false.

Comment: Overloading `Equals` without overriding it. WTF did they think. Personally I would have used reference equality, but this choice is just confusing.

Comment: You should explain about the difference between [`Object.Equals()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) and [`IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx)

Comment: Because we have two different references (objects, instances) and default Equal(object) should return reference comparison first.

Comment: @MatthewWatson - I don't think StringBuild implements `IEquatable<T>`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx

Comment: @Kobi Yep, although it *does* have something that would match it. Weird that they didn't add the interface. Probably it would have been a breaking change.

Comment: From your link: 
**It determines whether the two objects represent the same object reference. If they do, the method returns true.** This test is equivalent to calling the ReferenceEquals method. In addition, if both objA and objB are null, the method returns true.

Comment: @Uzzy - But what happens when the references are not equal? After null checks, it calls an overridden `.Equals(object)`, which may do anything. I don't think I understand exactly what you are saying, by the way. Is my answer wrong?

Comment: @Kobi - answer is right, my comment was addressed to CodesInChaos.  I am sorry for inconvenience

Comment: @Kobi `sb1.Equals(sb2)` calls `StringBuilder.Equals`, `sb1.Equals((object)sb2)` calls `Object.Equals`. Your answer looks right to me..

Comment: @MatthewWatson `IEquatable<T>` needs to equivalent to `object.Equals` (and consistent with `GetHashCode`). AFAIK it is mainly a performance optimization to avoid boxing on value types.

Answer (score 4):

You are using 4 different methods of comparison, result in different results:

- Operator `==` will by default do a check if the references are equal. In this case you have two instances, so they do have two different references. The behavior of `==` can overridden by any type (like `string` has its own method of comparison), but in case of the `StringBuilder` it is not.
- Method `StringBuilder.Equals(StringBuilder)` will compare with another StringBuilder and compares some inside values. These values are, in your case, the same. Strange thing is that `StringBuilder` does not override the method `StringBuilder.Equals(object)` to apply the same logic.
- Method `object.Equals(object, object)` will try to call the method `.Equals(object)` of one of the objects. In this case: `StringBuilder.Equals(object)` which, as I said, did not have the logic to compare the values. Resulting in just a compare of the references of both instances.
- `Object.ReferenceEquals` will just compare the references.

For more info, see:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f37cfeys.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx

Answer (score 3):

StringBuilder.equals does not compare the objects but rather
from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccth01t4.aspx):

> "True if this instance and sb have equal **string**, **Capacity**,
>   and **MaxCapacity** values; otherwise, false."

The rest of the checks you're doing compare the reference.